# python csv file put single quotes in some parts of the text

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, csv, quotes

There are 11 elements and there are missing single quotes in some words.
Example:

**Wrong:**

```
('360287910', '3600', '87965865825165', 'PHONE', '1', 'POC', '1','teste1, teste,Sim,5)
```

**It should be like this:**

```
('360287910', '3600', '87965865825165', 'PHONE', '1', 'POC', '1', 'teste1', 'teste','Sim','5')
```

**I tried:**

```
with open('('/content/drive/My Drive/Datasets/Data_base _case_VOC_arrumado3.csv', "w+", encoding="utf-8") as csv_file:
    csv_file.write(content.replace(''))
```

Comment: Have you tried reading that csv file with `pandas`?

Comment: Each line in the CSV file has () around it? - looks like each line is a tuple and not a properly formatted CSV file. Is there a typo in `'teste1` in your post with a missing single quote?

Comment: @DhanaD. yes, I have tried this, but it didn't work for this problem.

Comment: @CodeMonkey     sorry, it should be []: ['360287910', '3600', '87965865825165', 'PHONE', '1', 'POC', '1', 'teste1', 'teste','Sim','5']  in the csv file is without it, I gave it as an example, that's why I didn't put quotes in test 1. how would I solve it with python?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to quote all values in CSV file with single quote then you can try something like this:

```python
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO
import csv

s = "'360287910','3600','87965865825165','PHONE','1','POC','1','teste1',teste,Sim,5"

# comment next line and uncomment next line to read from file
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(s), quotechar="'", header=None)
#df = pd.read_csv('Data_base _case_VOC_arrumado3.csv', quotechar="'", header=None)

df.to_csv('output.csv', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL, quotechar="'", index=False, header=None)
```

**Output:**

```
'360287910','3600','87965865825165','PHONE','1','POC','1','teste1','teste','Sim','5'
```